# How to get label of an input field when submit a form in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, input, angularjs-ng-model

What I want to achieve is when I submit the form it should return the label of the option I choose in the console but it is returning me the value of the option.

Expected Result:
 DXBA-sky

Result getting:
 Dubai

**HTML**

```
<div class="suggestField">
    <input type='text' list='listid' placeholder="TO" ng-model="toCity" ng- change="suggestCity(toCity)">
    <datalist id='listid'>
          <option ng-repeat="item in fromSuggestData" label='{{item.PlaceId}}' value='{{item.PlaceName}}'>
    </datalist>
    <button ng-click="submitForm(toCity)">SUBMIT</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.fromSuggestData = {
    "PlaceId": "DXBA-sky",
    "PlaceName": "Dubai",
    "CountryId": "AE-sky",
    "RegionId": "",
    "CityId": "DXBA-sky",
    "CountryName": "United Arab Emirates"
}, {
    "PlaceId": "DUJ-sky",
    "PlaceName": "Dubois",
    "CountryId": "US-sky",
    "RegionId": "PA",
    "CityId": "DUJA-sky",
    "CountryName": "United States"
}
$scope.submitForm = function(toCity) {
    console.log(toCity);
}
```

Comment: Instead of ng-repeat use ng-options for options https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: @MarcusH Can you please show me how can I use ng-option for my solution? I am new to AngularJS.

Comment: Ofcourse, but please create a plunker or a working code snippet in the question with the current solution. Also include the complete controller.

Comment: the toCity model will contain the value of the option not the label. You have to change the value to whatever you want.

Comment: @neda I want to show the what is in the value and I want to take the label to controller when I submit.

Comment: You should use a select if you have a list of predefined option or use some autocomplete select like ui-select

Answer (score 3):

Here Is demo using ng-option.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.fromSuggestData = [{
    "PlaceId": "DXBA-sky",
    "PlaceName": "Dubai",
    "CountryId": "AE-sky",
    "RegionId": "",
    "CityId": "DXBA-sky",
    "CountryName": "United Arab Emirates"
  }, {
    "PlaceId": "DUJ-sky",
    "PlaceName": "Dubois",
    "CountryId": "US-sky",
    "RegionId": "PA",
    "CityId": "DUJA-sky",
    "CountryName": "United States"
  }];
  $scope.submitForm = function(toCity) {
    console.log(toCity);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" class="suggestField">
  <select id="cityname" ng-model="toCity" ng-options="item as item.PlaceName for item in fromSuggestData">
    <option value="">Select</option>
  </select>
  <button ng-click="submitForm(toCity.PlaceId)">SUBMIT</button>
</div>
```